# What's the difference between "full" and "fullest" in this context?

Tags: adjectives

> The importance of living life to the **full**.
>
> The importance of living life to the **fullest**.

Do these sentences mean the same thing? Is "full" or "fullest" more appropriate in this contest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***[To the full](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/to-the-full)*** is a saying meaning:

> - To the greatest possible extent:
>     *enjoy your free trip to Europe to the full* (ODO)
> - Fully; completely; taking the greatest advantage of the situation.
>     *Now that I'm retired, I feel I can live life to the full.*

The expression is also used also with the superlative "fullest", see [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=life%20to%20the%20full%2Clife%20to%20the%20fullest&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clife%20to%20the%20full%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clife%20to%20the%20fullest%3B%2Cc0) and the meaning is the same.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple:

> "Full" and "fullest" are all same and refer to one thing. Just imagine if a glass is filled to the brim, it is full. It cannot gain any more to be the "fullest", so the "fullest" is no more than "full". Thus, both the sentences mean one and same thing.

However, when you are emphatic, you may choose "fullest" so as to be more forceful; but you must remain alive to the fact that the "fullest" is no more in quantity than what "full" is.

Comment: Contrast emphatic with empathic. What do you mean by ***alive*** in "you must remain alive that ..."?

Comment: @Rathony -  Sorry! In hast, I accidentally typed "empathic" in place of "emphatic". "Alive" means being alert or aware. I have corrected that portion too. Sorry, for the silly mistakes I have accidentally committed.

Comment: No. It's not so simple. Although some adjectives (full, unique ...) are absolute and hence ungradable in their prototypic senses, they have derived senses in which they are considered gradable. Thus 'His glass is the fullest' is common for 'His glass is the most nearly full'; 'Their act is absolutely unique'. Here, 'to the full' and 'to the fullest **are** interchangeable (apart from emphasis, as you say); neither is taken as actually meaning 'in a way that could not conceivably be improved upon', but rather heading towards that ideal.